# Python Code for Tree Stored in 1d Array Contains Logic Error Relating to Right Node Pointer

Tags: python, arrays, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

In the following code from a CS textbook I am using, in the output for the tree after inserting the value `32`, the `RightPointer` for the node in array position `0` is set to `3`. This doesn't make sense to me as I thought it should still be `2`.

I looks like the code is incorrect, as there are two nodes with a `RightPointer` of `3` now. Can anyone please explain what I need to do to make the the code work correctly please?

I'm guessing this line is the culprit: `tree[PreviousNodePtr].RightPointer = NewNodePtr` as that is where the `RightPointer` updates, but I can't see how I would change it to avoid the problem.

```
# NULL should be set to -1 if using array element with index 0
NULL = -1


# Declare record type to store data and pointer
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Data = ""
        self.LeftPointer = NULL
        self.RightPointer = NULL


def print_tree(tree):
    print("{0:^5}|{1:^10}|{2:^10}|{3:^10}|".format("", "Left", "Data", "Right"))
    for i in range(len(tree)):
        index = "[" + str(i) + "]"
        print("{0:^5}|{1:^10}|{2:^10}|{3:^10}|".format(index, tree[i].LeftPointer, tree[i].Data, tree[i].RightPointer))

    print("RootPointer", RootPointer, "FreePtr", FreePtr, "\n")


def InsertNode(tree, NewItem):
    global RootPointer, FreePtr

    if FreePtr == NULL:
        # tree is full
        print("Tree is full")
        return

    # There is space in the array
    # Take node from free list and store data item
    NewNodePtr = FreePtr
    tree[NewNodePtr].Data = NewItem
    FreePtr = tree[FreePtr].LeftPointer
    tree[NewNodePtr].LeftPointer = NULL
    # check if empty tree
    if RootPointer == NULL:
        # insert new node at root
        RootPointer = NewNodePtr
    else:  # find insertion point
        ThisNodePtr = RootPointer
        while ThisNodePtr != NULL:  # while not a leaf node
            PreviousNodePtr = ThisNodePtr  # remember this node
            if tree[ThisNodePtr].Data > NewItem:
                TurnedLeft = True  # # follow left pointer
                ThisNodePtr = tree[ThisNodePtr].LeftPointer
            else:
                TurnedLeft = False
                ThisNodePtr = tree[ThisNodePtr].RightPointer
            if TurnedLeft:
                tree[PreviousNodePtr].LeftPointer = NewNodePtr
            else:
                tree[PreviousNodePtr].RightPointer = NewNodePtr


tree = [TreeNode() for i in range(5)]
RootPointer = NULL  # set Root pointer
FreePtr = 0  # set starting position of list
for i in range(len(tree) - 1):  # link all nodes to make free list
    tree[i].LeftPointer = i + 1

print_tree(tree)
InsertNode(tree, 10)
print_tree(tree)
InsertNode(tree, 5)
print_tree(tree)
InsertNode(tree, 20)
print_tree(tree)
InsertNode(tree, 32)
print_tree(tree)
```

Output:

```
     |   Left   |   Data   |  Right   |
 [0] |    1     |          |    -1    |
 [1] |    2     |          |    -1    |
 [2] |    3     |          |    -1    |
 [3] |    4     |          |    -1    |
 [4] |    -1    |          |    -1    |
RootPointer -1 FreePtr 0

     |   Left   |   Data   |  Right   |
 [0] |    -1    |    10    |    -1    |
 [1] |    2     |          |    -1    |
 [2] |    3     |          |    -1    |
 [3] |    4     |          |    -1    |
 [4] |    -1    |          |    -1    |
RootPointer 0 FreePtr 1

     |   Left   |   Data   |  Right   |
 [0] |    1     |    10    |    -1    |
 [1] |    -1    |    5     |    -1    |
 [2] |    3     |          |    -1    |
 [3] |    4     |          |    -1    |
 [4] |    -1    |          |    -1    |
RootPointer 0 FreePtr 2

     |   Left   |   Data   |  Right   |
 [0] |    1     |    10    |    2     |
 [1] |    -1    |    5     |    -1    |
 [2] |    -1    |    20    |    -1    |
 [3] |    4     |          |    -1    |
 [4] |    -1    |          |    -1    |
RootPointer 0 FreePtr 3

     |   Left   |   Data   |  Right   |
 [0] |    1     |    10    |    3     |
 [1] |    -1    |    5     |    -1    |
 [2] |    -1    |    20    |    3     |
 [3] |    -1    |    32    |    -1    |
 [4] |    -1    |          |    -1    |
RootPointer 0 FreePtr 4
```

Comment: I can't understand the logic of this algorithm. Do you think it works normally until input 32? What happens with 10, 5 and 20? They don't appear on the nodes.

Comment: It seems mostly correct although incredibly convoluted. The values are all there in the final output, but the pointer for node 0 is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not updating your `ThisNodePtr` . So `ThisNodePtr` pointer doesn't move left or right and therefore it always updates the root's left or right.

```
if TurnedLeft:
    if tree[PreviousNodePtr].LeftPointer != NULL:
        PreviousNodePtr = ThisNodePtr
        ThisNodePtr = tree[ThisNodePtr].LeftPointer
        tree[PreviousNodePtr].LeftPointer = NewNodePtr
    else:
        tree[PreviousNodePtr].LeftPointer = NewNodePtr 
else:
    if tree[PreviousNodePtr].RightPointer != NULL:
        PreviousNodePtr = ThisNodePtr
        ThisNodePtr = tree[ThisNodePtr].RightPointer
        tree[PreviousNodePtr].RightPointer = NewNodePtr
    else:
        tree[PreviousNodePtr].RightPointer = NewNodePtr
```

You can test it with `InsertNode(tree, 3)` instead of `InsertNode(tree, 32)`, too if you want. It will move left when the left node isn't `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution seems to work, but it seems that I get the same result by simply unindenting the section `if TurnedLeft:
            tree[PreviousNodePtr].LeftPointer = NewNodePtr
        else:
            tree[PreviousNodePtr].RightPointer = NewNodePtr` from the original version so it is outside the while loop. Would that also be a correct solution, or does it cause other problems please?

Comment: Actually, never mind my code. I tested both yours and mine with several inputs and mine has bugs. I feel like I can fix it if I spend some time but you already got the solution. So no need to spent time on that :)

Comment: It's a pretty complex thing to understand at pre-degree level, IMO.